# Webflow Flow Location By URI?

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a Spring MVC application that currently uses a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to integrate several webflows. The bean definition looks something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/process1/reservation.html">flowController</prop>

            <prop key="/process2/reservation.html">flowController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>
```

What I need to do is decide which web flow to execute based on the URI. The rest of the definition looks like this:

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    <flow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <flow:listener ref="flowExecutionListener" />
    </flow:flow-execution-listeners>    
</flow:flow-executor>

<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" >
    <flow:flow-location id="process1Reservation" path="/WEB-INF/flows/path/to/process1/reservationFlow.xml" />
    <flow:flow-location id="process2Reservation" path="/WEB-INF/flows/path/to/process2/reservationFlow.xml" />
</flow:flow-registry>
```

So, when I use the following URL, I expect to execute the first flow:

```
http://me.com/application/process1/reservation
```

(And similar with the second flow).

Am I overcompicating this? I do NOT want to create  definitions with id's like "process1Reservation" if I can avoid doing so.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can add wild card pattern to indicate (flow-location-pattern) that would create a rule as to how to register flows. This would enable you to register many flows with 1 rule instead of hard coding each one manually. (Note: below is the unofficial "standard and best practice" way to register flows)

```
<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions --> 
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

So the above rule states:

1. Start scanning in the `/WEB-INF/flows` directory (make sure it exists)
2. For any sub directories look for any files that have the suffix `-flow.xml`
3. For each match register this flow to the flow-registry

Once, you do this you can navigate to the registered flow by the url that it mapped to from anywhere in your application.

Using your example the flow:

```
/WEB-INF/flows/path/to/process1/reservation-flow.xml   // note: ends in "-flow.xml"
```

would be accessible via the http get request of:

```
http://(my-web-server-ip):(port)/path/to/process1
```

(**Note**: "flows" is NOT included in the url path because we set it as part of the `base-path="/WEB-INF/flows"` attribute in the flow-registry definition and note that the flow file name is not used at all in the request, only the directory the flow is defined in)

------------------- **Now to ANSWER the Question** --------------------------------

I would just create an MVC controller that redirects to the desired flow. Here is a crude example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/decideWhichFlow/{someUrlVal}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String decideWhichFlow(@PathVariable String someUrlVal) {

    String flowName = null;

    // exec some logic to decide which flow to use based on "someUrlVal" passed via url
    if(someUrlVal.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
        flowName = "process1";
    else 
        flowName = "process2";

    String redirectToFlow = "redirect:/path/to/" + flowName ;

    return redirectToFlow;  
}
```

Moreover, you could also create a master flow called "process" that can execute a "decision-state" that decides which sub-flows to call (subflow1,subflow2, etc...) based on some request Params but this might be overkill. I think the MVC controller solution is much simpler.

Also, the flow names "process1", "process2" will always be static. I don't see why would need to increment the names? If the increment has a special meaning in your application and is used in processing logic then you would pass it in as a request param in the flow and not make it a part of the flow name. If the flows represent different logic/process I would give them more meaningful names (e.g processReservation). No different than naming pojo class attributes. The name is only there for clarity as to the underlying function of the process.