# How url works in Spring Web flow?

Tags: spring-webflow

Below is my project url.
http://localhost:8080/springwebflow/loginFlow;jsessionid=k7338gzuvyc2sk36axkzhe9r?execution=e1s1

How **springwebflow/loginFlow** path works ? and with this path how my display_login.jsp come?

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Spring Web Flow</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/config/login-servlet-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/config/login-webflow-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.studytrails.tutorials.springwebflow" />

    <!--Define FlowHandlerMapping to tell DispatcherServlet (in web.xml)
          to send flow requests to Spring Web Flow -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="loginFlowRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Define FlowHandlerAdapter to handle Spring Web Flow request call.
            This is the Controller class in Spring Web Flow -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="loginFlowExecutor" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

login-servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Define the flow executor responsible for executing login web flow -->              
        <flow:flow-executor id="loginFlowExecutor" flow-registry="loginFlowRegistry"/>

        <!-- Define the registry that holds references to all the flow related XML configuration-->
        <flow:flow-registry id="loginFlowRegistry">
            <flow:flow-location id="loginFlow" path="/WEB-INF/flows/login-flow.xml"/>
        </flow:flow-registry>       

</beans>
```

login-webflow-config.xml

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>

<html xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">

    <body>
        <form action="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=loginCredentialsEntered" method="post"> 

            <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
            <br/>
            Enter login name as <b>alba</b> and password as <b>pass</b> for successfull login.
            <br/>
            Use any other login name and password for login error.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="loginName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br/>           
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

display_login.jsp

PFA are my files, could you please explain how flows works with url.

Answer (score 0):

So if i have understand your question, you want to display your jsp using the flow.
Normaly, we use an hiearchy like that:

vue
   -src/main/java
         -controllers
   -src/main/resources
           -Meta-INF
             -flows
                  -page-folder
                      -page-flow.xml
             -resources
                   -page-folder
                      -page.xhtml

Each folder has one file.xml, you can add a subFolder and then put your xml on it.
For your flow, it should be like that:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
parent="default">

<view-state id="myPage" view="/page-folder/page.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="pageController.init()"></evaluate>
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="cancel" to="close"/> 
   </view-state>

   </flow>
```

if you want to know how the views are rendered with the spring flow:
   https://spring.io/blog/2007/11/15/the-spring-web-flow-2-0-vision

It's better if you look in the official documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
my question is: 
When I hit on localhost:8080/springwebflow/loginFlow

How my display_login.jsp comes?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can add wild card pattern to indicate (flow-location-pattern) that would create a rule as to how to register flows. This would enable you to register many flows with 1 rule instead of hard coding each one manually. (Note: below is the unofficial "standard and best practice" way to register flows)

```
<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions --> 
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

So the above rule states:

1. Start scanning in the "/WEB-INF/flows" directory (make sure it exists)
2. For any sub directories look for any files that have the suffix "-flow.xml"
3. For each match register this flow to the flow-registry

Once, you do this you can navigate to the registered flow by the url that it mapped to from anywhere in your application.

Using an example flow:

```
/WEB-INF/flows/path/to/process1/reservation-flow.xml   // note: ends in "-flow.xml"
```

would be accessible via the http get request of:

```
http://(my-web-server-ip):(port)/path/to/process1
```

(note: "flows" is NOT included in the url path because we set it as part of the base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" attribute in the flow-registry definition and note that the flow file name is NOT used at all in the request only the directory the flow is defined in)

---

See this answer for more details: [Webflow Flow Location By URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411833/webflow-flow-location-by-uri/29427488#29427488)